# Writing to a large table whilst running mysqldump --single-transaction --quick

Tags: mysql

Can someone clarify the duration of the lock used to create the initial snapshot when using **mysqldump** with the ***--single-transaction*** and ***--quick*** options?

I have a large table (16GB, 101M rows) in a database (InnoDB) with binary logging enabled. I do not use any FK constrains on this table.

In order to keep the BIN LOG file count manageable I need to periodically update the mysqldump seed. I want to be able to run mysqldump whilst my service continues to add new records (approx 35/sec).

According to the MySQL documentation: A lock occurs when creating the snapshot and you can continue writing to the table. So is that instant or does it depend on the size of the table? *i.e. needs to read the entire contents before the lock is released.*

I am concerned that whilst the generating the snapshot I'll be unable to write to the table.

Can someone please clarify what happens as the table dump begins? Happy for a link that describes the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `--single-transaction` and `--master-data`, mysqldump does the following at the beginning.

```
FLUSH TABLES;
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION /*!40100 WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT */;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

After all of these are done, the actual backup starts.  The lock is only necessary so that `SHOW MASTER STATUS` returns exactly the correct binlog coordinates of the beginning of the transaction.

The backup should not block writes, and writes should not block the backup; however, existing transactions need to be committed or rolled back before the `FLUSH` statements will finish, and these can interact with established transactions in such a way that new transactions stall waiting for any old transactions that are still open.  But the issue will clear itself when those old transactions finish.  If you aren't leaving long-running transactions (as you shouldn't be), you should have no issue.

Comment: Great, so once the latest binlog PK is read the lock is released.Thx! How do I get the SQL above (query log)? I'd like to test the duration. Also, what if BINLOG was not used?